# Operator not applicable to this operand when I try to make filter based on date

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am kind of new to Delphi and Query and before I posted this question, I searched everywhere that related to my problem but it seems I was unable to find anything that could help me solve my problem.

I found this error message that operator not applicable to this operand type with this code:

```
SQL.Text:='SELECT COUNT(Nik) FROM Absent WHERE Nik LIKE' 
  +QuotedStr('%'+cxButtonEdit1.Text+'%') 'AND MONTH(Tgl)'= 
  +QuotedStr(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',dtp1.Date)')+ 'AND YEAR(Tgl)'= 
  +QuotedStr(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',dtp1.Date));
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `+` operator, and have some quotes mixed up. Instead of:

```
SQL.Text:='SELECT COUNT(Nik) FROM Absent WHERE Nik LIKE' 
  +QuotedStr('%'+cxButtonEdit1.Text+'%') 'AND MONTH(Tgl)'= 
  +QuotedStr(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',dtp1.Date)')+ 'AND YEAR(Tgl)'= 
  +QuotedStr(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',dtp1.Date));
```

I presume you mean

```
SQL.Text:='SELECT COUNT(Nik) FROM Absent WHERE Nik LIKE' 
  +QuotedStr('%'+cxButtonEdit1.Text+'%') +' AND MONTH(Tgl)='
  +QuotedStr(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',dtp1.Date))+ ' AND YEAR(Tgl)=' 
  +QuotedStr(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',dtp1.Date));
```

Note also that you must stop building queries this way. You are opening yourself up to [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/). Use parameterised queries instead.

Comment: im trying to add + operator like you've been told, but now it getting new error message like :
1. Missing Operator or semicolon
2. Undeclared identifier: 'Tgl'

Comment: You won't get that from the code in my answer since `Tgl` is only ever seen inside string literals. Before we proceed, can I ask if you fully understand my answer?

Comment: Yep, so far i do understand ur answer :)

Comment: Good. Because the code in my answer does compile. I checked. Obviously I had to replace `cxButtonEdit1.Text` with a string, and `dtp1.Date` with a `TDateTime`. But that was it.  Anyway, as I said, you have to stop asking for SQL injection. You need parameters. They make the code much more readable too.

Comment: oh god, it worked now. i do mistake at write )') + since it must be ))+
thanks sir, it worked now :)

and yep, i'll do learning more about parameters, im very new at delphi programming. thanks for your advice :D

Answer (score 4):

Your code has several flaws :

1. You are mixing some symbols.
2. You missed a space after the `LIKE` sentence
3. You are using the `FormatDateTime` function without a valid format to get the month or year of the date.
4. Finally you are not using parameters.

Try this sample (you must replace the `ADOQuery1` for the real Query component name)

```
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT COUNT(Nik) FROM Absent WHERE Nik LIKE :Nik');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('AND MONTH(Tgl) = :MonthTgl');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('AND YEAR(Tgl) = :YearTgl');

  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Nik').Value      :=  '%'+cxButtonEdit1.Text+'%';
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('MonthTgl').Value := MonthOf(dtp1.Date);
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('YearTgl').Value  := YearOf(dtp1.Date);

  ADOQuery1.Open;
```

Comment: i do try this and replace `ADOQuery1` with mine but i got error message 'Undeclared identifier : Parameters' can i get to know why that happen? im still confuse about Parameter

Comment: which component are you using to run the SQL sentence?

Comment: oh ya, im not using `ADOQuery` but `MyQuery` from MYDAC, is that parameter not working without `ADOQuery` ?

Comment: Ok, then try `MyQuery.ParamByName ('Nik').AsString := '%'+cxButtonEdit1.Text+'%';` and   `MyQuery.ParamByName ('MonthTgl').AsInteger:=  MonthOf(dtp1.Date);`